# GROUP BY on multiple joins

Tags: mysql, sql, database, rdbms

I have searched for the issue but could not have a working solution.

I have 3 tables: User, Post, Comments.

```
select u.id user
     , p.id post
     , c.id comm
  from USer u
  join Post p
    on u.id = p.user_id
  join Comments c
    on p.id = c.post_id;
```

This gives me an output with 3 columns that relates a user with the posts they have and the comments received on each.

The o/p is like:

```
user    post    comm
1    1    4
1    1    5
1    1    7
1    1    8
2    5    11
2    5    12
2    7    13
```

I wanted to find the user with the maximum number of overall comm. For this the `GROUP BY` on user is not working. What could be an alternative for the task?

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`.  `ORDER BY`.

Comment: "is not working" is not helpful. Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) But--

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GROUP BY`, `ORDER BY`, and `LIMIT`:

```
select p.user_id, count(*) as num_comments
from Post p inner join
     Comments c
     on p.id = c.post_id
group by p.user_id
order by num_comments desc
limit 1;
```

Note that because you only want the user id, you do not need the `user` table, because `user_id` is in `post`.